# false Transaction mined but execution failed after adding 1eth on the value's field in REMIX ide

Tags: transactions, blockchain, solidity, remix

i receive this errors "false Transaction mined but execution failed".

```
address public admin;

    constructor() {
       admin = msg.sender;
    }

   //data strcutures 
   mapping (address => uint) balance;
   mapping (address => bool) AccountActive;

  function deposit() public payable {
     balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
      
  }
```

Comment: Transaction deploying the contract? Or to the `deposit()` function? Does the sender have sufficient balance?

Comment: yeah when i add value, and when i try to deploy, fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're deploying a contract, sending along ETH value, the `constructor` needs to be use the `payable` modifier - just like any other function receiving ETH.

```
constructor() payable {
    admin = msg.sender;
}
```